# Opening files with long path in Windows using CMD bat

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

We sometimes need to allow users in our company to open files with long paths on Windows. One of the solutions I found (https://support.centrestack.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026297293-How-to-Open-Files-with-Very-Long-Paths-on-the-Windows-Client) looks very promising and easy to use:
1. We add a context menu item in Windows Explorer that runs our .bat file on the file selected:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Open with Shorter Path\command]
@="C:\\mapKAndOpen.bat \"%1\""
```

2. The bat file mounts a "drive" that contains short path to the file and opens the file from the short path.

   ```
   @echo off 
   subst.exe K: /D
   subst.exe K: "%cd%"
   explorer K:\%~nx1
   exit
   ```

Unfortunately, when I try to run the .bat file from the directory with long path, I get the error from Explorer.EXE: "The directory name is invalid." This happens even if I open an empty batch file that doesn't do anything.
So it looks like that for the conditions I have the Windows Explorer cannot start batch. Does anyone know why it might happen?

The path is quite long, something like the following:

> \\?\D:\TESTPaths\Documents - TEST\2 TestFolderLongName\2.1 dsf sfjsdklfjdslkfj sdklfj slkdfjskldjf klsjfsdkl jfsdkl jfsdlkj flksd jfsdkl jfksld fjsdklfj lksdfj sdklfj sdklfj klsdjf sldk jflsdkjf sdlkj fsdlf jsdf\2.1.1 dsf sfjsdklfjdslkfj sdklfj slkdfjskldjf klsjfsdkl jfsdkl jfsdlkj flksd jfsdkl jfksld fjsdklfj lksdfj sdklfj sdklfj klsdjf sldk jflsdkjf sdlkj fsdlf jsdf\2.1.1.1 dsf sfjsdklfjdslkfj sdklfj slkdfjskldjf klsjfsdkl jfsdkl jfsdlkj flksd jfsdkl jfksld fjsdklfj lksdfj sdklfj sdklfj klsdjf sldk jflsdkjf sdlkj fsdlf jsdf\2.1.1.1.1 dsf sfjsdklfjdslkfj sdklfj slkdfjskldjf klsjfsdkl jfsdkl jfsdlkj flksd jfsdkl jfksld fjsdklfj lksdfj sdklfj sdklfj klsdjf sldk jflsdkjf sdlkj fsdlf jsdf\2.1.1.1.1.1 Expense Report.xlsx

Maybe the issue is in my Windows version or some settings and the solution works for other ones, not sure.

Comment: I think that link is more for long names of files, rather than long path names. The example in it works because the path isn't too long. It really is important to educate users against using long folder & file names. It can play hell for backup solutions. I suspect it doesn't work for you because the path that you're trying to reference is too long itself.

Comment: @Smock yes, I think this is a correct remark. Unfortunately the solution only helps for the case of Excel file path longer than 218 characters, and not for any long path.
Thank you!